# What is an NFC SIM card and what is the different with regular SIMs?

Tags: mobile-phone, smartcard

If a phone has NFC capabilities, do you need an NFC SIM card to use NFC?

Is NFC a technology of the phone or of the SIM card? Or is the NFC SIM card just 'more secure' than a regular SIM Card **and if so, how/why?**.

Comment: Questions about electronic devices, media players, cell phones or smart phones are off-topic. See [On Topic](http://superuser.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NFC ([Near-Field Communication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Near_field_communication)) is a set of ideas and technologies that enable smartphones and other devices to establish radio communication with each other by touching them together or bringing them into proximity, typically a distance of 10 cm (3.9 in) or less.

> If a phone has NFC capabilities, do you need an NFC SIM card to use NFC?

No, in this case you have already a NFC chip installed in your phone :)

> Is NFC a technology of the phone or of the SIM card? Or is the NFC SIM card just 'more secure' than a regular SIM Card and if so, how/why?.

See above, neither nor. And nope, not 'more secure'.

The NFC SIM card is just a combination of a normally SIM card and a NFC chip in one card.

Comment: Does the NFC SIM need any antenna on the phone, or the NFC SIM has an embedded antenna also? I mean, can I insert the NFC SIM into an old phone(NOKIA 1100 for example) and the write something into the SIM using NFC?

Answer (score 7):

Some GSM operators are using "NFC SIM" term to refer to a SIM card with an additional financial application. Such a card in combination with a NFC phone can be used for contactless payments. There are different options:

1. it can act as a pre-paid debit card
2. your payments are added to your GSM bill
3. you can open an account in a bank partnering with the GSM operator.